# Disable DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS in ASP.NET Core 5 web app

Tags: .net-5, azure-appservice, asp.net5

When deploying my ASP.NET Core 5 app (which targets .NET 5) to an Azure App Service, it throws a 502 error with the following details logged:

```
<Event>
    <System>
        <Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/>
        <EventID>1026</EventID>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-07-12T08:58:41Z"/>
        <EventRecordID>-2033762671</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>RD0003FF7ABC48</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>Application: dotnet.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.721.25508
.NET Version: 5.0.7
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException: Startup hook assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\SDK\5.0.301\DotnetTools\dotnet-watch\5.0.301-servicing.21271.7\tools\net5.0\any\middleware\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll' failed to load. See inner exception for details.
---&gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\SDK\5.0.301\DotnetTools\dotnet-watch\5.0.301-servicing.21271.7\tools\net5.0\any\middleware\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll'. The system cannot find the path specified.
File name: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\SDK\5.0.301\DotnetTools\dotnet-watch\5.0.301-servicing.21271.7\tools\net5.0\any\middleware\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll'
at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)
at System.StartupHookProvider.CallStartupHook(StartupHookNameOrPath startupHook)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.StartupHookProvider.CallStartupHook(StartupHookNameOrPath startupHook)
at System.StartupHookProvider.ProcessStartupHooks()
</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

The path that is not found corresponds to the environment variable that is being set in the web.config, which is set automatically by VisualStudio when I build the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <!--App settings needed to the Cloud media service library-->
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="8088" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_AUTO_RELOAD_WS_ENDPOINT" value="ws://localhost:53593/MyWebApp/" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES" value="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh" />
        <environmentVariable name="DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS" value="**C:\Program Files\dotnet\SDK\5.0.301\DotnetTools\dotnet-watch\5.0.301-servicing.21271.7\tools\net5.0\any\middleware\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll**" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What is this environment variable used for? Can I disable its generation to allow the app run properly on the Azure App Service when deploying?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can manually delete this from web.config  if you don't need it, and don't check-in next time while creating app

Comment: Yeah, I can manually remove it from web.config but if I do, VS will create it again.

Comment: that is what I am saying, so don't check-in the web.config file again. so you new changes will not be considered during deployment

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please be more precise? What do you mean by not to check-in the web.config?

If you mean to leave it out via .gitignore or similar, I don't think this is a good practice, as new important changes made on this file in the future can also be ignored. I think it would be great if there was any option/statement to disable the creation of this env variable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most fancy solution, but to manually delete the DLL referenced in the `DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS` environment variable in the `web.config` prevents VS to automatically set it over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Startup hooks are disabled by default on trimmed apps. Not sure if you're in the position to do [app trimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options), but if you could, that'd effectively disable startup hooks.

The main reason for this [is explained here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-startup-hook.md), and comes down to it being potentially dangerous to be run on trimmed apps.

Another, scarier way, would be to write yourself a global startup hook that disables local startup hooks to load. Of course, the simpler solution is to just make sure that that environment variable is not set in the first place.